# How to loop through all excel sheets while opening an excel file from Oracle Forms Builder?

Tags: excel, oracle, ole, oracleforms

I want to read an excel file with the help of **CLIENT_OLE2** in my Oracle forms.
I succeed to do that if the excel just has one sheet because this sheet is the activesheet, but if I have several sheets in my excel,I am not able to read the desired sheet.

```
    ----------------Get the file to open        ---------------------------

    v_fName := :upload.ti_file_name_upload;

    IF ( v_fName IS NOT NULL ) THEN 
    
      clear_form ( no_validate );

    --------------INITIATE EXCEL APPLICATION---------------------------

    application := CLIENT_OLE2.create_obj('Excel.Application'); 
    CLIENT_OLE2.set_property(application,'Visible', 'false');
    
----------------GET WORKBOOKS FROM EXCEL APPLICATION---------------

    workbooks := CLIENT_OLE2.Get_Obj_Property(application, 'Workbooks');
    
    ----------------OPEN REQUIRED WORKBOOK-----------------------------
    
    args := CLIENT_OLE2.CREATE_ARGLIST;
    CLIENT_OLE2.add_arg(args,v_fName); 
    workbook := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbooks,'Open',args);
    CLIENT_OLE2.destroy_arglist(args);

----------------OPEN REQUIRED WORKSHEET----------------------------
 
    worksheets := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbook, 'Worksheets');
    worksheet := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(application,'activesheet'); 

----------------Specify columns that must be read------------------
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I replaced

```
worksheets := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbook, 'Worksheets');
worksheet  := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(application,'activesheet');
```

with

```
args:= CLIENT_OLE2.create_arglist; 
CLIENT_OLE2.add_arg(args, 'Sheet Name');   
worksheet := CLIENT_OLE2.GET_OBJ_PROPERTY(workbook, 'Sheets', args);
CLIENT_OLE2.destroy_arglist(args);
```

and now it works fine!